# Cannot play the video in VideoCapture in python

Tags: python, opencv

I have tried the video capture program using opencv in python. The code is given below

```
from cv2 import *
a=VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    b,c=a.read()
    imshow("video",c)
    if(waitKey()==ord('s')):
        break
a.release()
destroyAllWindows()
```

For the above code,my webcam is opening.But the video is not playing and i have tried with many videos still it displays like an image.How can i make the video play.Could anyone provide solution???

Comment: check this link https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-video-python-opencv-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your if condition. The correct way is this

```
import cv2 as cv

a = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    b, c = a.read()
    cv.imshow("video", c)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
a.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: You must change the VideoCapture parameter to 0 (I have two cams so for me 1 is the right number). Now I edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```